# How to open folder from remote system using java

Tags: java, remote-desktop

I'm trying to perform some actions on Remote Desktop,i'm able to login successfully but not able to access remote desktop folders after login,it is checking in local machine,Please help me how to perform such actions.

Below is the Steps,need to perform on remote desktop only

```
1.Login into Remote Desktop(I did it)
2.Go to Particular folder path in remote desktop
3.Open XML config file in remote desktop
4.Edit Dates in above file
5.Save it
6.Now come to 2nd step folder
7.Run Job scheduler
8.Verify Data in Database
9.Same flow for multiple Schedulers
```

Below is the code to open Folder in Remote desktop but it is trying to open in local machine.

```
public void accessFolderPath() throws IOException{

         Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            File dirToOpen = null;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dirToOpen = new File("D:\\wwwroot\\jobs");
                desktop.open(dirToOpen);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: Actually ,i'm trying to automate the scheduler process bu login into remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can access the local folders of remote desktop on your own machine by making a connection to it without actually logging in to remote desktop.

Windows + R or in windows explorer type - 
\\IP or host name of Remote Desktop\DRIVE$\FOLDER_PATH

it will ask for username and password for the first time after every restart or shutdown.

Comment: As per your answer,particular folder should be shared,other wise it will not feasible,in my case folder is not shared.